# Restful Web Service Cannot access WADL

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans

I am trying to make a Restuful web service in netbeans. I have gone to `new project -> Java Web -> Web Application`. After, i right clicked and picked `Restful Web Services from patterns`. The code is:

```
import com.sun.xml.bind.v2.WellKnownNamespace;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXB;

/**
 * REST Web Service
 *
 * @author Administrator1
 */
@Path("welcome")
public class WelcomeRESTXMLResource {

    @GET
    @Path("{name}")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public String getXml(@PathParam("name") String name){

        String message = "Welcome "+ name;
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        JAXB.marshal(message, writer); //convert string to xml
        return writer.toString();
    }

}
```

So when i right click again on project and click `test restful web services` and web test client in project this appears:
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B72DE0EFE15750DA!106&authkey=!AGTGB2BjQelAE9s&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng 
Why is this happening???